# Updating column values based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, numpy

In the `DataFrame` below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Ve_Paper', 'Buy', '-','Canada',np.NaN),
                  ('Ve_Gasoline', 'Sell', 'Done','Britain',np.NaN),
                  ('Ve_Water', 'Sell','-','Canada,np.NaN),
                  ('Ve_Plant', 'Buy', 'Good','China',np.NaN),
                  ('Ve_Soda', 'Sell', 'Process','Germany',np.NaN)], columns=['Name', 'Action','Status','Country','Value'])
```

I am trying to update the `Value` column based on the condition if `Action` is `Sell` check if the `Status` is not `-` if that is true then the first two characters of the `Country` needs to be updated as the `Value` column else if `Status` column is `-` the `Value` column needs to be  updated with the `Name` column without the characters `Ve_`, if `Action` is not `Sell` leave the `Value` column as `np.NaN`

What I have tried so far is

```
import numpy as np
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Action']== 'Sell',df['Country'].str[:2] if df['Status'].str != '-' else df['Name'].str[3:],df['Value'])
```

but I am getting the output as `<pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x000001EDB8F662B0>` wherever Iam trying to extract substrings
so the output looks like this

```
       Name     Action    Status      Country       Value
   Ve_Paper        Buy         -       Canada      np.NaN
Ve_Gasoline       Sell      Done      Britain  <pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 662B0>
   Ve_Water       Sell         -       Canada  <pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x000001EDB8F662B0>
   Ve_Plant        Buy      Good        China      np.NaN  
    Ve_Soda       Sell    Process     Germany  <pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x000001EDB8F662B0>
```

But the `output` I am expecting is

```
       Name     Action    Status      Country       Value
   Ve_Paper        Buy         -       Canada      np.NaN # Because Action is not Sell
Ve_Gasoline       Sell      Done      Britain          Br # The first two characters of Country Since Action is sell and Status is not "-"
   Ve_Water       Sell         -       Canada       Water # The Name value without 'Ve_' since Action is Sell and the Status is '-'
   Ve_Plant        Buy      Good        China      np.NaN  
    Ve_Soda       Sell    Process     Germany          Ge
```

As mentioned in the answer below the method I tried works for someone but doesn't work for me. Is there any alternative approaches or better approaches than what I have tried, since that is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I do not see any problem in here. Could you please elaborate it more if possible?

I am sharing my piece of code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([('Ve_Paper', 'Buy', '-','Canada',np.NaN),
                  ('Ve_Gasoline', 'Sell', 'Done','Britain',np.NaN),
                  ('Ve_Water', 'Sell','-','Canada',np.NaN),
                  ('Ve_Plant', 'Buy', 'Good','China',np.NaN),
                  ('Ve_Soda', 'Sell', 'Process','Germany',np.NaN)], columns=['Name', 'Action','Status','Country','Value'])

df['Value'] = np.where(df['Action']== 'Sell',df['Country'].str[:2] if df['Status'].str != '-' else df['Name'].str[3:],df['Value'])
print(df)
```

You can also try with the below code:

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Action']== 'Sell', df['Country'].astype(str).str[0:2], df['Value'])
```

Comment: Yes I was expecting that answer but it doesn't work for me, I couldn't find any reason for that not to work, but somehow it doesn't instead it is giving me the String object's address as output whenever I am trying to get a substring as I have mentioned in the question. Hope someone here can explain why that happened

Comment: Have you tried removing pandas and installing it again?

Comment: I tried that but still no joy, Is there any alternative approaches you can suggest?

Comment: Not sure if it will work out for you or not but try this one as well:
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Action']== 'Sell', df['Country'].astype(str).str[0:2], df['Value'])

Answer (score 0):

Using np.select was a great choice

```
conda = df.Action.eq('Sell')
condb = df.Status.eq('-')
df['value'] = np.select([conda&condb, conda&~condb],
                        [df.Name.str.split('_').str[1],df.Country.str[:2]],
                        default = np.nan)
df
Out[343]: 
          Name Action   Status  Country  Value  value
0     Ve_Paper    Buy        -   Canada    NaN    NaN
1  Ve_Gasoline   Sell     Done  Britain    NaN     Br
2     Ve_Water   Sell        -   Canada    NaN  Water
3     Ve_Plant    Buy     Good    China    NaN    NaN
4      Ve_Soda   Sell  Process  Germany    NaN     Ge
```